# Vercel not deploying because of "@"?

Tags: typescript, next.js, module, namespaces

I've been seeking for a while, and, maybe it's because of how I made my researches, but nevermind I'll ask it anyway.

I'm working on a react.js/next environnement, then I worked on a library I had to customize, which is in Typescript. No problem to handle that, but when I deployed the final version on Vercel, I had  3 errors.

```
./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/audio.js
    13:06:35.878    Module not found: Can't resolve '@mantine/core' in '/vercel/path0/helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common'
    13:06:35.879    
    13:06:35.879    Import trace for requested module:
    13:06:35.880    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/audio.js
    13:06:35.880    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/index.js
    13:06:35.881    
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/audio.js
    13:06:35.881    Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/ArrowRightAlt' in '/vercel/path0/helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common'
    13:06:35.881    
    13:06:35.881    Import trace for requested module:
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/audio.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/index.js
    13:06:35.881    ./helper/react-gutenberg/index.js
    13:06:35.881    
    13:06:35.882    ./helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common/audio.js
    13:06:35.882    Module not found: Can't resolve '@mantine/hooks' in '/vercel/path0/helper/react-gutenberg/dist/blocks/common'
```

The point seems to be that there is an "@" in the namespace, and when i build the file with tsc, the js file isn't handling this @ when it requires it. Thanks a lot for your help

I tried to deploy on Vercel but it didn't work at all, failed to compile.